# PythonAnywhere How to handle multiple "web workers" or processes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, pythonanywhere

Summary of my website:  A user fills in some information which after hitting "submit" the information is submitted to the backend via AJAX.  Upon the back end receiving the information, it generates a DOCX using the information and serves that DOCX file back to the user.

Here is my AJAX Code in my HTML File

```
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'/submit/',
        data:{
            data that I submit
        },
        dateType: 'json',
        success:function() {
           document.location = "/submit"; 

        }
    })
```

My Views Function for /submit/ that uses send_file to return file

```
def submit(request):

    #Receive Data
    #Create a File with the Data and save it to the server

    return send_file(request)

def send_file(request):

    lastName = get_last_name() +'.docx'
    filename = get_full_path() # Select your file here.                                
    wrapper = FileWrapper(open(filename , 'rb'))
    response = HttpResponse(wrapper, content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=' + lastName
    response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(filename)

    return response
```

This has worked flawlessly for sometime now.  However I started having problems when I increased the amount of "web-workers"/processes from 1 to 4 in my hosting account.  Whats happening is a different web-worker is being used to send the file, which is creating a new instance of the site to do that. The problem with that is that the new instance does not contain the file path that is created with the web worker that creates the file.

Like I said, this worked flawlessly when my webApp only had one "web worker" or one process.  Now I only have roughly a 50% success rate.

Its almost like a process is trying to send the file before it has been created. Or the process does not have access to the file name that the process that created it does.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Code Trying to send path_name through request and then back to the server.

Submit View returning file info back to ajax.

```
def submit(request):
   # Receive DATA
   # Generate file with data

    lastName = get_last_name() +'.docx'
    filename = get_full_path() # Select your file here.


   return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'lastname': lastName,'filename':filename}), content_type="application/json")
```

Success Function of AJAX

```
 success:function(fileInfo) {
        name_last = fileInfo['lastname']
        filepath= fileInfo['filepath'] 
        document.location = "/send";  
    }
```

So can I get the fileINfo to send with the "/send" ?

Comment: Please add get_full_path(), it's needed to debug.

Answer (score 1):

Each web worker is a separate process. They do not have access to variables set in another worker. Each request could go to any worker so there is no guarantee that you'd be using the file name that was set for a particular user. If you need to transfer information between requests, you need to store it outside of the worker's memory - you could do that in a cookie, or in a database or a file.

Comment: Okay, How do I go about doing that?  I tried sending the file_path through the submit return which was working.  But I couldn't figure out how to get the success function to submit the file path back.  Does that make sense? I added the code I tried to the bottom of above.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Nevermind, I got it working!  I used cookies to hold the file path.  Thanks for your help